# Connected to wifi successfully, but no internet connection

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I'm a relatively new macOS user. Let me try to describe the problem I'm facing as succinctly as possible

Just this morning, when I'm unable to get any internet connection even though WiFi is connected (full strength). All my other devices has no issues when connected to the same network (it's my home network)

I've logged into the router, and checked, there are no blacklisted IP/MAC addresses.

Additional information

1. I'm using a tMBP 15" for over a year
2. I've had no issues with any WiFi connectivity to my home network before today.
3. ping from terminal doesn't work as well.
4. I'm able to connect to my phone's hotspot, and get internet from my MBP.
5. I have bootcamp set up. When I boot into Windows, I'm able to get internet access through my home WiFi

How can I troubleshoot this to get to the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Forgive the obvious question, but what happens if you switch off your modem/router, wait a minute, and then switch it back on?

Comment: Maybe a DNS issue? Try using Google's DNS servers http://osxdaily.com/2015/12/05/change-dns-server-settings-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've provided great troubleshooting info, we can isolate the problem to being your Mac and not your router, we can isolate the problem to OSX and not your WiFi card, etc.

I want to say it's an IP address problem. Maybe Windows has taken the IP address that your router gave your Mac's MAC address. I'd recommend going to system preferences --> Network. On the left column does WiFi say "connected" or "self-assigned IP" or something else? In the mean time, I'd recommend going to system preferences --> Network--> select WiFi on the left column --> click advanced on the bottom right --> TCP/IP tab --> Renew DHCP lease.

If this doesn't work, you can try on the WiFi tab (instead of TCP/IP), select your WiFi network and then click the minus (-) button to remove it, click OK, and try to reconnect to the WiFi network again.

If that doesn't work, you can hold option and click on the WiFi symbol on your menu bar (top right). Does your IP address look right? If you're not familiar with networking let me know what your IP address and router address are and we can go from there.